# Serializing data structures to a file with Haskell?

Tags: serialization, haskell, file-io, io

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to figure out how IO works. I have a data structure, a tree, that I want to serialize to a file and then de-serialize back out to the data structure. It seems like I should be able to do it through show and read, but my use of read is throwing an error. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
data Tree = Answer String | Question String Tree Tree deriving (Read, Show)

fileToTree :: (Read a) => FilePath -> IO a
fileToTree filePath = do 
    dataStruct <- readFile filePath
    return (read dataStruct)

treeToFile :: (Show a) => a -> FilePath -> IO ()
treeToFile dataStruct filePath = do
    writeFile filePath (show dataStruct)

main = do
    let filePath = "data.txt"
    let ds = fileToTree filePath
    ask ds
    treeToFile ds filePath

ask :: Tree -> IO ()
ask (Question q yes no) = do
    putStrLn q
    answer <- getLine
```

The error I'm getting is "Couldn't match expected type 'Tree' against inferred type 'IO a' in the first argument of 'ask'". It seems like the read should return a Tree type, but it's returning an IO type. Is there a way to coerce it to a Tree type, or am I totally mis-reading the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `fileToTree` returns a value in `IO`. This means that the line `let ds = fileToTree filePath` is binding an `IO a` to the `ds` identifier. If you want to work on the value you obtain in the `IO` monad, then you need to use the `>>=` (bind) function from the `IO` monad by replacing the `let ds = fileToTree filePath` line with `ds <- fileToTree filePath`. This will bind something of type `a` to `ds`, in a sense stripping off the outer `IO`. The call to `ask` will finally unify `a` with `Tree`.

With that out of the way, there seems to be an issue with `ask`. What you have above doesn't compile, and it seems as though you are not using `answer`, so I am guessing that this was an error in pasting your code.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to unwrap the IO in the fileToTree function by doing something like `return (read dataStruct :: Tree)`, which was causing errors because fileToTree wasn't returning an `IO a`. Unwrapping it in main is something I never thought of.